# deleted default constructor headache

Tags: c++

My c++ book says this (lippman, c++ primer, fifth ed., p. 508):

> The synthesized default constructor is defined as deleted if the class ... has a const member whose type does not explicitly define a default constructor **and** that member does not have an in-class initializer. (emphesis mine)

Why then does this code produce an error?

```
class Foo {
  Foo() { }
};

class Bar {
private:
  const Foo foo;
};

int main() {
  Bar f; //error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'Bar'
  return 0;
}
```

The rule above seems to indicate that it should not be an error, because Foo does explicitly define a default constructor. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think your quote is *relevant* here, because `Foo` *does* explicitly define a default constructor. It is not true that the quote says that your code is OK.

Comment: @KerrekSB you're right, but then the book must be omitting some other rules I should also know about, because none of the other rules mention anything relevant about the default constructor. (there are 4 rules on when the copy control members and the default constructor are deleted.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix your error. You need to make Foo::Foo() public.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() { }
};
```

Otherwise I do believe it is private.

Is this what your looking for?

Comment: No problem, pleasure to help.

Comment: Also, the Bar class needs a constructor, otherwise it doesn't know how to initialize the private foo member.

Comment: @GangYin Isn't foo supposed to be just default-initialized i.e. use the Foo's default constructor by default?

Comment: @user2015453, I just get that from c++ primer 5th edition : "we must use constructor initializer list to provide values for members that are CONST, reference, or of a class type that doesn't have a default constructor."

Comment: The main question is not addressed in this answer. It is 'call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of Bar.'. This is because, Bar has a non static constant member, and it can't be initialized by the default constructor, therefore, it is implicitly deleted.

Answer (score 5):

The default constructor is omitted when a a class construction isn't trivial.

That in general means that either there is an explicit constructor that receives parameters (and then you can't assume that it can be constructed without those parameters)

Or if one of the members or base classes need to be initiated in construction (They themselves don't have a trivial constructor)

Comment: But if Foo has no explicit constructor, why is the construction of Bar not considered trivial (and thus skipped/deleted)? Foo is pretty trivial, with or without this explicit constructor, which actually does nothing!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this should work

```
class Foo {
  public:
  Foo() { }
};

class Bar {
public:
  Bar() : foo() {}
private:
  const Foo foo;
};
```