# Creating layers with new members in Cocos2D-X?

Tags: c++, constructor, cocos2d-x

In Cocos2D-X, I've created a pointer to the current scene to initialize a GameObject manager (in attempt to abstract away some of the Cocos2D API).

My header looks like:

```
class GameplayScene : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{

private:
    CCTMXTiledMap *_tileMap;
    CCTMXLayer *_background;
    CCSprite *_sprite;
    CCPoint _firstPoint;
    ObjectManager objectManager;

public:
    void feedback(CCObject * swipe);
    bool isBlocked(CCPoint point);



    // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
    virtual bool init();

    // there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
    static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();

    void update(float delta);

    CCPoint tileCoordForPosition(CCPoint position);
    CCPoint tileToPosition(CCPoint position);

    // a selector callback
    void menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender);

    // implement the "static node()" method manually
    CREATE_FUNC(GameplayScene);
};
```

However, I'm promptly told that I'm making a call to "implicitly deleted default-constructor". Can anyone explain to me what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

make GameplayScene constructor public like this

```
class GameplayScene : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{
public:
    GameplayScene() {}
```

Same as "[deleted default constructor headache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564709/deleted-default-constructor-headache)".